# What resources are available "just beyond" the scope of SO?

Tags: discussion

I checked out Code Review, and did a search on this meta; I found a few things:

- Programmers is for "whiteboard" questions
- Typically, Code Review is not for broken code or bugs
- Stack Overflow code should be limited to the specific problem or area that you feel is giving you trouble

I basically stretched SO's scope as far as possible with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074240/methodology-of-high-dimensional-data-structuring-in-r-vs-matlab) on R methodology, but I'd still like to know more.

*(Specifically, related to that refactoring question I have some bug, whose location I can't pick out, and for which I can't build a toy example, that makes my results in R useless (although quite pretty) and incomparable to what I can get in MATLAB. Doing it in MATLAB is "fine" but I feel like a failure as a learner if I don't figure it out.)*

Is there a community wiki thread (didn't find one in a search on meta) or can you recommend any specific tutoring sites for (online or offline) programming help that (asymptotically) approaches hand-holding? I'm pretty dumb, guys :)

Answer (score 1):

None that Stack Exchange provides. You might find tutoring sites elsewhere, though.

Stack Exchange really isn't about tutorials or introductions - the unofficial motto is "specific answers to specific questions" - which excludes tutorials.

Comment: Do you know any specific sites you would recommend?

Comment: I don't really have any generic recommendations off the top of my head. It would depend on the language, the context, the problem, etc... plus, this isn't exactly the place. Sorry!